# Table Border strangeness

Tags: html, html-table

I was making some modifications to a page, massively restructuring how a table is generated, while trying to keep the front-end of the page identical.  I succeeded for the most part, except now the table border is a bit screwy.

This is how the page should look:
[image]

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

This is effecting, to some degree, every table that I've redone.

The original was one table, with empty cells to fill out the spacing.  Since some of the links only appear if a user has certain permissions,

All of the tables in question have the following definition (with the width changed)

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width='180'>
```

I tried setting a table border = 1 on the outer table, and while it drew the lines I needed, it did not eliminate the inner lines and made it look worse.

Thoughts as to what could be causing this?

EDIT:  Added upon request the whole code of the table below.

```
<!--Enterprise Codes Section Start -->
<div class='tabbertab <%=strEnterprise%>' title='Enterprise Codes' id='mytab1'>
<div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class='SectionTable' width='700'>
<tr valign=top>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width='150'>
    <tr>
          <td class='aaa'>People</td>
    </tr>
    <% for i = 0 to UBound(peopleArray)%> 
        <tr>
            <td class='nograph'><A href='<%=peopleArray(i).link%>'><%=peopleArray(i).title%></a></td>
        </tr>
    <%next%> 
    </table>    
</td>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width='150'>
<tr>
      <td class='aaa'>Organization</td>
</tr>
 <% for i = 0 to UBound(orgArray)%> 
    <tr>
        <td class='nograph'><A href='<%=orgArray(i).link%>'><%=orgArray(i).title%></a></td>
    </tr>
<%next%> 
</table>    
</td>
<td>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width='150'>
        <tr>
            <td class='aaa'>Skills</td>
        </tr>
        <% for i = 0 to UBound(skillsArray)%> 
            <tr>
                <td class='nograph'><A href='<%=skillsArray(i).link%>'><%=skillsArray(i).title%></a></td>
            </tr>
        <%next%>
    </table>    
</td>
    <td>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width='250'>
        <tr>
            <td class='aaa'>Communications</td>
        </tr>
        <% for i = 0 to UBound(commArray)%> 
            <tr>
                <td class='nograph'><A href='<%=commArray(i).link%>'><%=commArray(i).title%></a></td>
            </tr>
        <%next%>
        <td class='aaa'>Other</td>
        </tr>
        <% for i = 0 to UBound(otherArray)%> 
            <tr>
                <td class='nograph'><A href='<%=otherArray(i).link%>'><%=otherArray(i).title%></a></td>
            </tr>
        <%next%>
            <%strSql = "Select NVL(CL_USER_DEFINED_HELP_FLD, 'N') CL_USER_DEFINED_HELP_FLD from client_tbl WHERE CL_CLIENT_ID_FLD = " & CLIENT_ID 
            Set adoConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            Set rsClient = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

            adoConnection.Open dsn_connection
            rsClient.Open strsql, adoconnection

            if rsClient("CL_USER_DEFINED_HELP_FLD") = "Y" then
                userHelpText = "Disable "
                toggleUserHelp = "N"
            else
                userHelpText = "Enable "
                toggleUserHelp = "Y"
            end if

            rsclient.Close()
            adoconnection.Close()
            %>
            <% if ADMIN = "Y" then %>
                <tr>
                    <td class='nograph'><A href='Maintenance/toggle_user_help.asp?toggleMode=<%=toggleUserHelp %>'><%=userHelpText %>User Defined Help</A></td>
                </tr>
            <% end if%> 
    </table>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div> 
</div>
```

Code for the .css for SectionTable

```
 TABLE.SectionTable
 {
BORDER-RIGHT: #a3cce6 1px;
BORDER-TOP: #a3cce6 1px solid;
BORDER-LEFT: #a3cce6 1px solid;
BORDER-BOTTOM: #a3cce6 1px solid;
 }
```

Comment: All I can say, based on the info in your post, is "undo the modifications". If you want more, then you will need to provide more information.

Comment: undoing the modifications would mean destroying 4 hours of work and turning the table from dynamic back to hard-coded.  Updated to include more of the code

Comment: Apparently, there's a TD .css definition somewhere other than the three .css files I was looking at, and that defines the borders. Because I don't have any td tags where the border is missing, that's why it doesn't appear.  Fun times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to use CSS on this, this is how your css file should look like.

```
table, tr, td, {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

this will merge all the borders of the table, tr, and td tags..

cuz as by default... there's a little bit of margin between all of them.
Try this instead...

```
TABLE.SectionTable, TABLE.SectionTable > tr, TABLE.SectionTable > tr > td
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and also tried adding this to the SectionTable part of the .css and it didn't work